# How do I wrap text in .Rmd output to PDF without hyphen?

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, word-wrap

I have a `Shiny` app that writes a webpage and provides both an **Excel** file download and a **PDF**, through an `.Rmd` because I need to parameterize by country. See my previous question for the [same project on how to remove empty space in the PDF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64210913/how-do-i-remove-empty-space-between-code-chunks-in-rmd-output-to-pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64210913/how-do-i-remove-empty-space-between-code-chunks-in-rmd-output-to-pdf)

The PDF output is in columns: left side for tables, blank mini middle column for white space, right side for charts. I add table titles as text (I did not add them as captions because I wanted the titles formatted a certain way and couldn't figure it out that way as I don't know LaTeX). Some of the titles are long, and wrap mid-word with a hyphen. How do I make the PDF output wrap without breaking up a word?

For example, I'd like a long title to break between "with" and "extralong", without specifically telling it to break there (because my titles are dynamic, each PDF might need to wrap at a different spot(s) in the title), and then again probably between "through" and "hyphenation". Here's the R chunk where I create a long title and the colorize function:

```
long_title <- paste0("This really long title continues forever with extralong words that shouldn't break through hyphenation")

## https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/font-color.html
colorize <- function(x, color) {
  if (knitr::is_latex_output()) {
    sprintf("\\textcolor[HTML]{2A64AB}{%s}", x)
  } else if (knitr::is_html_output()) {
    sprintf("<span style = 'color: %s;'>%s</span>", color, x)
  } else x
}
```

The call:

`**r colorize(long_title, color = "#2A64AB")**`

The output, NOT the way I want it:

[image]